# app runs on iphone 5s, but not on iphone 5 (viewWillAppear stils gets called)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have tested my app on iPhone 5s. It runs beautifully. When I run in on iphone 5, it crashes right after viewWillAppear: method with error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` printed in the App Delegate. The debugger only says `lldb`. I don't get it. What is going on here? What settings should I check so that the app us allowed to run on iphone 5?

I am using swift and Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

Comment: Just try following steps 1) clean your project from xcode 2) clean from device 3) Restart device 4)Add break point in viewWillAppear  and see line by line. These are the simple steps amy be you are missing something which may help.

Comment: At the (lldb) prompt, type `bt` and include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: When you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS activating Zombie Objects could be helpful. Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects.

Comment: I am sorry guys, I can't post any more details right now. I was at a local store and they were kind enough to let me try out the old device. I will supply more info tomorrow, possibly with a new question.